# Agrupacion por meses

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, eloquent, laravel-6, carbon

Quiero armar un select con todos los meses con los que se registro algun registro. Para luego crear consultas de esto.
Es decir. Por ejemplo
Se crean registros en el mes de enero-20 , febrero-20, abril-20... Por lo que unicamente en el select tienen que aparecer

- enero-20
- febrero-20
- abril-20

Por lo cual estoy haciendo el siguiente scope

```
public function scopeMonthRecords()
{
    $months = $this->groupBy('date_new')->get();

    return $months;
}
```

Esto me esta agrupando la consulta por días. Ya probe utilizar de agregar ->format('YY-mm') pero me arroja el siguiente error

> BadMethodCallException
>   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::format()
>   http://intranic.test/reports/panel

Como puedo agruparlo por mes ?

Comment: Para agruparlo en la consulta a BD, posiblemente puedas lograrlo con alguna expresión raw, pues el groupBy de Query Builder sólo acepta un string con el nombre de la columna como parámetro. Si no, puedes obtener los datos sin agrupar en la consulta, y usar el groupBy de las colecciones, con el que sí puedes pasarle una función como parámetro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve investigando y utilice DB::RAW, para lo que cree el siguiente scope

```
public function scopeMonthRecords()
{
    $months = $this->orderBy('date_new')->groupBy(DB::raw("MONTH(date_new)"))->get();

    return $months;
}
```

Con esto ya puedo generar un listado de unicamente los meses donde se crearon registros agrupado por meses.